# Batch set command returned value to variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a simple batch script that get a file's size and set it into a local variable within the batch file.

I've tried a few variations but I keep getting the following error:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
```

substitution is invalid: %~zI

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET me=%~n0
SET parent=%~dp0

SET var = 
FOR %I in (C:\listener.log) DO CALL %~zI
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample line to replace it with:

```
FOR %%a in ("C:\listener.log") DO set "size=%%~za"
```

Comment: @DavidFaiz Explain how it didn't work.  Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this:

```
@echo off
call :getFilesize tnsnames.ora
echo %fileSize%
exit /b

:getFilesize
set filesize=%~z1
exit /b
```